# Vega-lite: Hover tooltips at fixed position

Tags: altair, vega-lite

1 How can the tooltips be shown at a fixed position, not at the position of the cursor ?

2 How to show crossshairs with indicator at the position of the cursor ?

[image: demo image]

Can you please help on this.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think this is possible in vega-lite so you could add it as a feature request on their issue tracker https://github.com/vega/vega-lite